# Robolectric uses incorrect resource id from library when inflating view

Tags: resources, robolectric

This is not exactly a question as I found the solution for the problem. Just hope it will help others who can encounter it.

We use Robolectric to write unit tests for a project which uses a library (actually several libraries). The libraries as well as application uses a lot of resources.

Lets suppose that Eclipse workspace contain project Library (with "library.package" as top package) which creates an Android library and project Application (with "app.package" at the top) which uses Library. the project Test is Robolectric project which refers to the Application project.

All of a sudden we found that very simple test which checks for existence of a particular view in the activity fails. For example:

```
@Test
public void testProgressBarInit() {
    LoginActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();

   assertTrue(activity.findViewById(R.id.status_text) instanceof TextView);
```

}

The library project implements the LoginActivity and defines an appropriate resources (layout). Failing tests run perfectly before we changed our code structure a little bit eliminating one more library.

Running the test under debugger showed that findViewById call uses correct value of the R.id.status_text taken from Application/gen/R.java file. At the same time, we discovered that the value of R.id.status text in the Application/gen/R.java differs from the value in Library/gen/R.java. Also, the Appication/gen directory contains file library.package.R.java which contains the same value for status_text as in the Application/gen/R.java (which differs from original one in the Library/gen/R.java). It is normal behavior of aapt tool which can change resource ids while merging resources from the library and the application.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigations we found the following:

1. Robolectric loads resource IDs which was defined in the library twice: once using R.class from application project and another using R.class from the Library project
2. which class is loaded depends on the class path configuration
3. to run tests we need to export the Library project from the Application project
4. if Library project is exported before Application/gen folder in the class path configuration, Robolectric replaces resource ids by those found in the Library/bin/classes/library/package/R.class
5. if Library project is exported after Application/gen folder, Robolectric uses correct resources found in the Application/bin/library/package/R.class.

It is certainly a bug in the Robolectric implementation as it should not load resource ids from R.class associated with library package. All ids are propagated to the Application/gen/R.java (see [discussion here on GitHub](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/469#issuecomment-19214994)).

If you encounter this or similar problem with resource usage while using Robolectric, make sure that you export library project after Application/gen folder in the Build Path-Order and Export configuration.